# I've had Tomboy twice delete a single important note. What's going on there?

Tags: tomboy

Not sure what's going on here, but here's the best I can describe:

- I use Tomboy extensively, for notes, collecting throw-away passwords,etc.
- Once a couple of months ago, a very important note just disappeared. No reference to the title, no deleting, no way of tracking it down---it was just like it had never existed.
- The same thing just happened today.  I think the note in question was actually open when I rebooted, so maybe that's related.

Has anyone else encountered something similar?

***EDIT: Happened 3 times***

Seems to be the last note I have open when shutting down (which is usually the most important) is deleted without a trace.

Comment: It looks like a bug in Tomboy. What I can advise is to make a backup copy fo such notes. However I am trying to reproduce described behavior. EDIT: It does not repreduce such behaviour on my PC.
Lucid x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm short-handing this answer as "There is a currently unresolved error in Tomboy."**

It seems like this is what's going on here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/580333

A note is overwritten with 0 data.  So it neither enters the Backup folder, nor is the data recoverable from the trash.

No one has yet been assigned to the bug.